# What is the alternative for instance parameter in snow_record_find ansible module?

Tags: ansible, servicenow

I have tested the Ansible snow_record_find module towards my own ServiceNow Developer Instance and it is working fine. However, when I want to implement it in my project Testing environment by using my own company ServiceNow, I got error mentioned "HTTPSConnectionPool(host='domainname.com**.ng.service-now.com**', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: //ap".

From this link: (https://github.com/ansible/awx/issues/2515), I found out that it has something to do with the instance parameter as the host parameter highlighted by the error shows that the ".service-now.com" is appended to my company ServiceNow instance url.

Hence, I concluded that is why I got this error. But, when I try to find out other alternative parameter for the instance like 'host' or 'url', there isn't anything like that.

Or perhaps, there is other work around that I can do for this? The main objectice here is using this module to retrieve record from ServiceNow table by using Query as shown as in the Ansible snow_record_find documentation: (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/snow_record_find_module.html)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Regrettably, it appears the `snow_record_find` module [only supports `instance`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.9.6/lib/ansible/module_utils/service_now.py#L50), and (as you experienced) [`pysnow` prioritizes `instance` over `host`](https://github.com/rbw/pysnow/blob/0.7.13/pysnow/url_builder.py#L46)

It appears based on some traffic on [a similar PR](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/66184) that they are now suggesting that one use the new [ansible collections functionality](https://github.com/ServiceNowITOM/servicenow-ansible)

If you're not on ansible 2.9, then "forking" the `snow_record_find.py` into the `library` folder of your playbook is the only recourse I know of through which you can add a `host` module arg and then pass that arg into `pysnow.OAuthClient` to behave like you wish

Comment: Currently I am using Ansible 2.9, means the work around u mentioned is not possible? I am also not clear about the "forking" you have mentioned.

Comment: If you're on ansible 2.9, then don't worry about the forking because that's not the future -- it was the only way that ansible used to have of fixing their bugs; you'd `mkdir library; cp /path/to/ansible/modules/notification/snow_record_find.py library/snow_record_find2.py; vi snow_record_find2.py` in order to make the new `snow_record_find2` module, containing your fixes, available to that specific playbook

Comment: I saw this and read the code for pysnow.  
Annoying, I have a related error as pysnow adds the `.service-now.com` on my company's domain instance. We do not use this as as our domain.  I can't use pysnow now or I have to modify it for our needs.  I'm looking at forking and editing the library.